# How to run chef-client in daemon mode and log it to a file as it logs when run from a tty?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I know how to run the chef-client in daemon mode and log it to a file.

```
chef-client -d -i 60 -l info -L /var/log/chef/client.log
```

The problem now is that it does not output the same log format as it does when it is run from a terminal. Is there a way to run chef-client in daemon mode and also obtain the same log format as it returns when run from a terminal? How to enable live_stream and capture the output in the chef-client events?

Answer (score 2):

Use `--force-formatter` from [the documentation](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html).
FWIW check the doc of [client.rb](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client.html), most options are configurable there also.

And there's the [chef-client](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/chef-client) cookbook to manage the configuration and how the client behave.

Comment: I have tried with `chef-client -d -i 60 -l info -L /var/log/chef/client.log --force-formatter` option too but no luck.

Comment: Aww, remove the -L and use standard redirection (>> /var/log...). Formatter won't work when output is a file. I did forgot that.

Comment: When running as a daemon Chef does not output anything to STDOUT. [Chef::Daemon - /lib/chef/daemon.rb](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/db57131ad383076391b9df32d5e9989cfb312d58/lib/chef/daemon.rb). Does this mean that whatever I am trying is impossible?

Comment: Maybe, I mainly use a crontab to launch chef periodically (since when the daemon version had problems, fixed since long ago) Maybe you could use this pattern ?

Comment: I can confirm this --force-formatter works. Just run chef-client without -L and redirect stdout and stderr(if want) to same file using normal bash redirection . 

I used it like this ->

`chef-client --force-formatter 2>&1 | tee t.log`

Comment: It would help if everyone specified what version of `chef-client` they are working with. Something confirmed for one version won't necessarily work for a different version.